# spring-data-neo4j PropertyReferenceException when creating custom repository

Tags: java, spring

I ran into problem while implementing a custom repository in **Spring Data Neo4J**. I have a node entity `Competence`. Here is code of this class

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@NodeEntity
public class Competence extends AbstractGraphElement {

    /** ID of the competence */
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    /** Competence's short name */
    private String name;

    /** Code of the competence */
    private String code;

    /** Description of the competence */
    private String text;

    /** Level of the competence */
    private int level;

    private int minAge;

    private int maxAge;

    /** Corresponding node's x coordinate */
    private Float x;

    /** Corresponding node's y coordinate */
    private Float y;

    @Relationship(type = "REQUIRES", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Requirement> requirements = new ArrayList<>();

    // ... Getters and Setters
}
```

And I have `CompetenceRepository` that extends `GraphRepository<Competence>` and custom `CurriculumRepository`

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "competences", path = "competences")
public interface CompetenceRepository extends GraphRepository<Competence>, CurriculumRepository {

    Competence findByName(@Param("name") String name);

    Competence findById(@Param("id") Integer id);

    Collection<Competence> findByNameLike(@Param("name") String name);

    Collection<Competence> findAllByGraphId(@Param("graphId") UUID graphId);

    Collection<Competence> findAll();

    @Query("match (a:Curriculum) where ID(a) = {id} with a MATCH (c:Competence)-[:IS_PART_OF*]->(a) RETURN c")
    Collection<Competence> findByCountry(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Query("MATCH (c:Competence) WHERE ID(c) IN {ids} with c match p = (c)-[*0..1]-(c2:Competence) where id(c2) in {ids} RETURN p, id(c)")
    Collection<Competence> filterGraphByCountry(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);

    @Query("match (c:Competence) where c.code =~ {code} and toString(c.level) =~ {level} and toString(c.minAge) =~ {minAge} and toString(c.maxAge) =~ {maxAge} WITH c MATCH p=(c)-[*0..1]-(d:Competence) where d.code =~ {code} and toString(d.level) =~ {level} and toString(d.minAge) =~ {minAge} and toString(d.maxAge) =~ {maxAge} return p, id(c)")
    Collection<Competence> findAllByCodeAndLevelAndMinAgeAndMaxAge(@Param("code") String code, @Param("level") String level, 
            @Param("minAge") String minAge, @Param("maxAge") String maxAge);

    @Query("match(c1:Competence)-[r:REQUIRES]->(c2:Competence) return c1, r, c2 LIMIT {limit}"/* "match(n) return n" */)
    Collection<Competence> graph(@Param("limit") int limit);
}
```

Here is `CurriculumRepository`

```
public interface CurriculumRepository {

    Collection<Competence> findByCountry(@Param("country") String country);
}
```

And its implementation class `CurriculumRepositoryImpl`

```
public class CurriculumRepositoryImpl implements CurriculumRepository {

    @Override
    public Collection<Competence> findByCountry(String country) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

When I run the application I get the exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property country found for type Competence!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:89) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.derived.DerivedGraphRepositoryQuery.<init>(DerivedGraphRepositoryQuery.java:68) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryMethod.createQuery(GraphQueryMethod.java:106) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(GraphQueryLookupStrategy.java:45) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.Neo4jRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(Neo4jRepositoryFactoryBean.java:66) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
... 43 common frames omitted
```

What can be a problem here?

Comment: You don't have a property named `country`  in `Competence` class. Naming convention has to be appropriate with spring-data. Use appropriate property name instead of non-existing property.

Comment: I want to create my own implementation of `findByCountry()`, that will execute a query that I will construct in this method. But If I use an existing property I will get a default implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have country property in your Competence class. you can still override the default implementation provided by JPA for findByCountry using @Query annotation provided by spring.